# Using W3C validator linkcheck - how do I know where the bad link is?

Tags: hyperlink, w3c-validation

I am using the W3C linkcheck tool to scan an entire domain, using these settings:  summary only, hide redirects and both don't send header choices are Deactivated.  I'm checking docs recursively, with a depth of 3.

The problem is that I've found a bad link, but it doesn't list it in context, i.e., which page it was found on.  It tells me what the referring page is, but the bad link is not on that page.   I've manually scoured the pages that seem to make sense, in that they appear near the bad link in the linkcheck output, but haven't found the culprit.  Is there any way to tell what page the validator found the bad link on?